# Is it possible to run an existing Linux Mint installation on an SSD via a virtual machine on Windows?

Tags: linux-mint, windows, virtual-machine

I used to run Linux Mint and Windows 10 (on separate SATA SSDs) via dual-boot, but I recently got a new PC running Win10 on an M.2 SSD. The SSD containing the Linux Mint installation hasn't been touched since.

My question is: Is it possible & not-too-difficult to re-run the Linux Mint SSD by connecting it to my new machine via SATA as a Virtual Machine on Windows? My goal is to run the SSD as a VM whilst preserving all my old Linux Mint files, programs, and settings.

Extra questions:

- Which Windows 10 VM program would you recommend for this?
- Will the fact that the Linux Mint SSD was used with dual-boot make
  this task harder?
- Could you recommend some guides or tutorials for this task?
- If this isn't possible, could you recommend a solution that will bring me nearest as possible to the end-goal?

Comment: VirtualBox can be used. It is also possible to use a physical disk, but I did that too long ago to remember details...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible.
I use such setup.
Create regular VirtualBox.
But to access physical disk you need to create virtual disk from command line.

For Windows:

VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename "C:Users<user_name>VirtualBox VMs<VM_folder_name><file_name>.vmdk" -rawdisk .PhysicalDrive#

https://www.serverwatch.com/guides/using-a-physical-hard-drive-with-a-virtualbox-vm/